# My code crashes javascript console

Tags: javascript

My code is freezing Chrome (and Firefox), won't execute on Coderbyte console but when I submit the code as an answer to the exercise, it does take.

```
var numOrdered = 0;
var numReversed = 0;
var tries = 0;
function KaprekarsConstant(num) {
  var arr = [];
  while (num > 0) {
    arr.unshift(num % 10);
    num = num / 10 | 0;
  }
  arr.sort();
  numOrdered = Number(arr.join(''));
  numReversed = Number(arr.reverse().join(''));

  while (num !== 6174) {
    num = numReversed - numOrdered;
    tries += 1;
  }
  return tries;
};

KaprekarsConstant(8593);
```

Why is it crashing? How can I prevent it?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Because of an infinite loop? Have you tried stepping through it line by line?

Comment: What are you trying to crush? That doesn't make much sense

Comment: what is num0, is that supposed to be num

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "crush" and "crushing"?

Comment: `while (num !== 6174) {
    num = numReversed - numOrdered;
    tries += 1;
  }` ... you do realise this will never change - I mean, the first time it isn't true, num will change to some other value ... but after that, nothing changes in that loop ... therefore ... infinite

Comment: @CertainPerformance You changed the original code in your edit. It should say num>0 not num0.

Comment: @kojow7 Oops, thanks, I should be more careful. Was trying to fix the formatting

Comment: What I'm trying to solve is: Arrange the digits in descending order and in ascending order (adding zeroes to fit it to a 4-digit number), and subtract the smaller number from the bigger number. Then repeat the previous step. Performing this routine will always cause you to reach a fixed number: 6174.

Comment: So it's not an infinite loop since at some point it should reach 6174. Of course I'm doing something wrong but I can't realize what.

Comment: One thing that is useful in debugging is to use console.log() to output values so that you can tell if they are in fact what you expect them to be.  In your second while loop, for example, try: `console.log(num)`. Or use modulus and output every tenth num to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everybody for the answers!!

Thanks to *@Jaromanda X* I realise the last while loop was infinite, since

```
num = numOrdered - numReversed;
```

will always be the same.

I realised I had to re-arrange the numbers every time so I create a function for that and incorporate it into the while loop.

I also added a bit of code from *@traktor53* to add the leading zeros in case of a number with less than 4 digits.

And to finish I declare

```
var tries = 0;
```

inside the function so it will start from zero in each run.

.

.

Final result:

```js
var numOrdered = 0;
var numReversed = 0;

function KaprekarsConstant(num) {
  var tries = 0;
  function order(num) {  // function to order the numbers
    var arr = [];
    while (num > 0) {
      arr.unshift(num % 10);
      num = num / 10 | 0;
    }
    while(arr.length<4) {  // leading zeroes as required
    arr.unshift(0);
  }
    arr.sort();
    numOrdered = Number(arr.join(''));
    numReversed = Number(arr.reverse().join(''));
  }

  while (num !== 6174) {
    order(num);
    num = Math.abs(numOrdered - numReversed);  // larger - smaller
    tries += 1;
  }
  return tries;
};

KaprekarsConstant(8593);
```

Answer (score 0):

the actual problem is the second `while` loop:

```
while (num !== 6174) {
  num = numReversed - numOrdered;
  tries += 1;
}
```

Removing it, your code doesn't hang the browser:

```js
var numOrdered = 0;
var numReversed = 0;
var tries = 0;
function KaprekarsConstant(num) {
  var arr = [];
  while (num > 0) {
    arr.unshift(num % 10);
    num = num / 10 | 0;
  }
  arr.sort();
  numOrdered = Number(arr.join(''));
  numReversed = Number(arr.reverse().join(''));

  
  return tries;
};

console.log(KaprekarsConstant(8593));
```

You need to revisit the logic in the second loop so that it doesn't become infinite.

Answer (score 0):

The second loop makes your code to hang up.Try this. I have made some changes.

```
var numOrdered = 0;
var numReversed = 0;
var tries = 0;
function KaprekarsConstant(num) {

  while (num !== 6174) {
     var arr = [];
    while(num >0){  
    arr.unshift(num % 10);
    num = num / 10 | 0;
  }
  arr.sort();
  numOrdered = Number(arr.join(''));
  numReversed = Number(arr.reverse().join(''));
  num = numReversed - numOrdered;
  tries += 1;
  }
  return tries;
};

KaprekarsConstant(8593);
```

Comment: i have made some change now. check this code. the second while loop is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop in the post keeps calculating the same value for `num`, so it it is not immediately 6174, the loop continues forever.

Basically the code is not following the algorithm for demonstrating Kaprekar's constant as shown on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6174_(number)):

- pad numbers of less than 4 digits with leading zeroes,
- subtract the smaller number from the larger of  { number, number with reversed digits), and
- repeat from the step of extracting digits from the latest subtraction result.

**Spoiler alert** - here's a working example of a recursive function with the extra pieces of logic:

```js
"use strict";

function KaprekarsConstant(num, tries=0) {

  if( num == 6174)  // Kaprekar's constant.
     return tries;
  if( num == 0)     // degenerate case, digits are the same
     return -tries;

  var arr = [];
  while (num > 0) {
    arr.unshift(num % 10);
    num = num / 10 | 0;
  }
  while( arr.length<4) {  // leading zeroes as required
    arr.unshift(0);
  }
  arr.sort();
  var numOrdered = Number(arr.join(''));
  var numReversed = Number(arr.reverse().join(''));

  num = Math.abs( numOrdered - numReversed)  // larger - smaller
  return KaprekarsConstant( num, ++tries);   // try again
};

// and test
function test() {
  var num = Number(input.value);
  if( Number.isNaN(num) || num < 1 || num > 9999) {
    throw new Error("Enter number between 1 and 9999");
  }
  console.log("Tries = %s", KaprekarsConstant(num)  );
}
```

```html
<label> Enter 1 to 4 digit number: <input type="text" id="input"></label><br>
<button type="button" onclick="test()">Calculate tries</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answers do address your question, the solutions and the code are missing the part about leading zeros as in wiki [Kaprekar's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6174_(number))
and the whole solution is very simple

```
function KaprekarsConstant(num)
{
    var tries=0;
    var numOrdered =0;
    var numRevesed=0;
    while(num!=6174)
    {
        numOrdered=("0000" + num).substr(-4,4).split("").sort().join("");
        numRevesed=numOrdered.split("").reverse().join("");
        num = numRevesed-numOrdered;
        tries+=1;
    }
    return tries;
}
KaprekarsConstant(8593);
```

Answer (score 0):

To the reason for 'Why is it crashing?', its maybe due to **Infinite Loop** .

The response I got when I try to run your code

```
Possible infinite loop detected. 
Error: Infinite loop
    at KaprekarsConstant (script 19:68)
    at script 27:1
```

Comment: Interesting, what are you running in, I've never seen that before